# Why doesn't JsonResponse automatically serialize my Django model?

Tags: json, django, python-3.x

I have these models:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class User(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Post(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content_url = models.URLField(null=False)
```

I want to be able to fetch all of the models in the database. When I do this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.get_all_posts, name="get_all_posts")]

def get_all_posts(request):
    return JsonResponse({"posts": Post.objects.all()})
```

I get an error about JSON serialization. So, as per the advice on other posts, I do this:

```
def get_all_posts(request):
    posts = serializers.serialize('json', Post.objects.all())
    return JsonResponse({"posts": json.loads(posts)})
```

But then I get an object of this shape:

```
('[{"model": "api.post", "pk": 1, "fields": {"created_at": '
 '"2019-05-06T20:22:43.928Z", "updated_at": "2019-05-06T20:22:43.928Z", '
 '"user": 1, "content_url": "tmp/posts/None.md"}}]')
```

Do you see how ridiculous this is? To get the actual content of the post, I need to map each "response" to its `fields` property, and even then, I am still missing the primary key!!

I'm wondering why the JSON response interface isn't as simple as this:

```
def get_all_posts(request):
    return JsonResponse({"posts": Post.objects.all()})
```

It seems that to deliver a serialized JSON to the client I have to jump through a series of hoops that, honestly, should not exist in a production web framework.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can make your own [*serializer*](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) to specify *how* a model should be serialized. In fact you answer exactly your question: because there are a large number of ways to serialize models, you probably do not want to include hashed passwords of your user model for example. In fact if you make a REST api, you better use `ViewSet`s, and thus do *not* construct all sorts of views yourself.

Comment: What I'm saying is that a subset of serializations are so common that they should happen out of the box

Comment: Some models aren't serialisable to JSON in a straightforward way. What to do with ManyToMany relationships? ForeignKeys? date and datetimefields? which format to use? Django Rest Framework gives you serialisers for many cases that make the job easier, but look at the code to understand that serialising objects isn't obvious. The way you want your JSON isn't the way everyone else wants their JSON.

Comment: I am not using DRF and do not plan to. I'd like to be able to do this with only Django.

True, there are many ways to seriailze, but a common way should be given out of the box with the option to extend if need be.

Comment: @dopatraman: what if you add extra attributes on the fly to a model? What if that is a HTTP session for example (something that is not really "serializable"). The Linux zen is: "let every tool do one job, and do that job very good". Usually it is better to design a system out of very small elements that can be reused effectively.

Comment: Django serialisation specifically targets dumping and loading data from the database, so its format (`serializers.serialize`) works nicely for that. Any other serialisation you should do yourself. DRF's serialisers are perfect for APIs. Note: I use DRF only for the serialisers, nothing else. No issue with that. They make it especially easy to also deserialize POST requests.

Answer (score 0):

Use `queryset` `values()` / `values_list()` methods for serialization:

```
def get_all_posts(request):
    return JsonResponse({"posts": Post.objects.values_list()})
```

it also supports spanned fields, so there will be no nested serialization, which is prone to errors:

```
def get_all_posts(request):
    return JsonResponse({
        "posts": Post.objects.values('content_url', 'user__username')
    })
```

but for some complex fleid values it may fail as well. In such case convert complex types to simple Python types in comprehension loop, or use a third party serializer like DRF or tastypie.